# Run different MonetDB databases at same time

Tags: database, server, connection, port, monetdb

I'm trying to run two servers listening to different ports in MonetDB, but I can't configure the ports.

I tried to include in M5server.bat:

set "mapi_port=50001", set mapi_port=50001, set port=50001, any combination of set and port, basically, still it does not work. The server is still listening to the default 50000.

Answer (score 0):

The option `--set mapi_port=50001` ought to work.  Note the leading `--`, I don't see them in your question.

I must admit I've never run MonetDB on Windows so it's possible I'm missing something.

Joeri